Docker error: "ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to copy: local error: tls: bad record MAC"
I am building a very simple streamlit application with mysql database. My dockerfile for streamlit looks like this:
# Use the official Python image
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Streamlit application files
COPY app.py .
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose Streamlit port
EXPOSE 8501

# Run Streamlit app
CMD ["streamlit", "run", "app.py", "--server.address=0.0.0.0"]

COPY network-rules.sh /app/
RUN chmod +x /app/network-rules.sh
# CMD ["/app/network-rules.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/network-rules.sh"]

And it throws error while I try to build an image out of it:

[+] Building 3.7s (7/12)                                                                                                                                                              docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.streamlit.original                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 926B                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim                                                                                                                                    2.5s
 => [auth] library/python:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim@sha256:2851c06da1fdc3c451784beef8aa31d1a313d8e3fc122e4a1891085a104b7cfb                                                                              1.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/python:3.9-slim@sha256:2851c06da1fdc3c451784beef8aa31d1a313d8e3fc122e4a1891085a104b7cfb                                                                              0.0s
 => => sha256:04acf592cf1a560c87343c39e76e3372e54bed9bcdc59bbc2c5289ff4eeb9e08 5.88MB / 14.71MB                                                                                                       1.1s
 => => sha256:89790d4ca55c29720fc29c489ba4403f3bb6baa1a6d8b5d0e96c3d40521408c0 0B / 3.33MB                                                                                                            1.1s
 => => sha256:92c3b3500be621c72c7ac6432a9d8f731f145f4a1535361ffd3a304e55f7ccda 0B / 29.16MB                                                                                                           1.1s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 658B                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => ERROR [2/7] WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
------
 > [2/7] WORKDIR /app:
------
Dockerfile.streamlit.original:5
--------------------
   3 |     
   4 |     # Set working directory
   5 | >>> WORKDIR /app
   6 |     
   7 |     # Copy the Streamlit application files
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to copy: local error: tls: bad record MAC

Please help, this is my very first project.
I tried checking the directory from the docker desktop but couldn't find any issue.
